# Using http get along with angular guards

Tags: angular, model-view-controller, .net-core

I'd like to protect routes using very simple authentication rule. Basically, I have a controller that reads my custom http header and use this header value to check user if it's in the local database or not. if I have a user then it's authenticated. The user is handled at the backend with a simple where clause. So my goal is to protect the route if the user is not authenticated.

Here is my `UsersController.cs` class:

```
    [Route("/api/[controller]")]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMapper mapper;
    private readonly IUserRepository repository;
    public UsersController(IMapper mapper, IUserRepository repository )
    {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<UserForDisplayDto>> GetAllUsers()
    {
        var headerValue = Request.Headers["customHeader"];  
        var person = headerValue.ToString(); 
        var users = await repository.GetAllJhedUsers(person);
        return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<User>, IEnumerable<UserForDisplayDto>>(users);
    }

}
```

Here is my corresponded `repository` class:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetAllJhedUsers(string id, bool includeRelated = true)
    {            
        return await context.Users.Where(x => x.JHED_ID == id).ToListAsync();
    }
```

My `AuthGuard` class is:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
  if (this.userService.isAuthenticated()) {
      return true;
   }
   this.router.navigate(['/errorpage]);

   return false;
 }
}
```

I have added this `AuthGuard` to the `app.module.ts` class as a `provider`. 
Here is my route that I need to proted:

```
{ path: 'members/members-list', component: MembersListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
```

Here is my `isAuthenticated` method in the `user.service.ts`:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;

constructor(private http: Http) { }


getAllUsers() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'users').map(res => res.json());
}

isAuthenticated() {
    const user = this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'users')..map(res => res.json());
    return !!user;
   }
}
```

The issue is that `AuthGuard` is **NOT** protecting the route when a user which is not in the local database visits the link. 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you know what `user` is before `!!user`? It's **not** the response body. Note that an auth guard can return an *observable* of a boolean, that's probably your best option here. Read up on RxJS and Angular's `Http` (or, better, the newer `HttpClient`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user` will always be an observable object which is truthy so you will always return true.

If your service returns an array, I'm thinking you'll want this:

```js
isAuthenticated(): Observable<bool> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'users')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .map(users => !!users.length);
}
```

Comment: Well, this code works but I had another problem that I couldn't catch. It was in the `canActivate()` method. I made a small changes and it worked as expected.

Answer (score -1):

You have to subscribe the observable to return the actual result:

```
isAuthenticated() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'users')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .Subscribe(users => 
              {
                 return !!users;
              });
}
```

Comment: This is completely incorrect. the `subscribe` method returns a `Subscription` object: `subscribe(...): Subscription` https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/f128f4d4d4f084b1358f61431bffb1ef7028eb1a/src/internal/Observable.ts#L70-L188